# fullpage.js slider and section

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using the fullpage.js plugin with three sections and several slides on each section.  if im on section 1 slide 3 and i go down to section 2 slide 1, upon returning to section 1 the whole section reverts back to section 1 slide 1.

I want to be able to move sections and upon returning to a section, have them stay on the same slide.

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs <- Documentation

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't ask `gimme the codezzz` kind of question. what have you tried? post your problem, preferably on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if im on section 1 slide 3 and i go down to section 2 slide 1, upon returning to section 1 the whole section reverts back to section 1 slide 1.

That's simple not true. You can check that [in the demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and it doesn't react in that way.

You might be using some wrong links...